# how to set the decimal separator for printing to file different from the system setting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Using VBA in Excel 2010 I want to print the contents of a cell in a worksheet which is a decimal number to a file. I am using the ´Print #´ statement for this. I am working in an environment where the comma ´,´ is the system wide decimal separator. For the printout I want the point ´.´ to be the decimal separator.

The following code does NOT work:

```
Public Sub printDecimal()
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Open "testfile.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    Close #1
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
End Sub
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264278(v=office.14).aspx) for the Print # statement says:

> All data written to the file using Print # is internationally aware;
> that is, the data is properly formatted using the appropriate decimal
> separator.

When I change the system wide settings in Windows 7 Enterprise Control Panel, I get the desired output, but this is not what I want.

Comment: One might consider using the 'Write #' statement instead of the 'Print #' statement. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264524(v=office.14).aspx) says that 'Numeric data is always written using the period as the decimal separator.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a macro, you can take direct control of the material being output to the text file:

```
Public Sub printDecimal()
    Dim st As String
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\testfile.txt" For Output As #1
    st = Range("A1").Text
    st = Replace(st, ",", ".")
    Print #1, st
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Using the **.Text** property allows you to get the cell's value WYSIWYG.  The rest is just string manipulation.

**EDIT#1:**

The reason the posted code does not work is that applying *Application.DecimalSeparator* is akin to applying formats......the underlying value does not change.  Run this to see the difference:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim st As String, st2 As String
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "|"
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\testfile2.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value & vbCrLf & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
    Close #1
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Gary's Student. This gives me what I need, but with a little extra processing. I want to be as concise as possible. Does anyone have an idea why the code that I quoted in my question does not do what I want?

Comment: @FelixSchneider  I am sure I am not explaining this clearly, but see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Almost there! When I use the '.' instead of the '|' I get the comma replaced by the point, but when I try to set the ThousandsSeparator to the empty string, it doesn't care.

Comment: @FelixSchneider  Now you see why I do not rely on system or application separators.  I can SEE what is in the cell.  **.Text** allows me to grab what I see.................the rest is just string manipulation.